# Keyboard shortcuts doesn't work anymore in Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, keyboard

I accidentally pressed combination of keys on my keyboard which I don't know what it was. Now, some keyboard hotkeys don't work anymore and the writing cursor doesn't match the "insert" mode.

For example, when I press Ctrl+f, the effect is the same as pressing the right arrow. Ctrl+v has the effect of pagedown.

At the same time, the writing cursor started showing the opposite as it was supposed to be. If I'm in "insert" mode, the cursor shows as a line. If I'm not in "insert" mode, the cursor shows as a square.

I couldn't find any explanation for this. Not even on internet. Is there anyway to go back to the default settings?

Comment: Did you perhaps change the language of your keyboard? That could have an affect on certain key combinations.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: There's an option of deleting the browser data/cookie/history. / Could be vim/emacs mode or something.

Comment: With Overleaf, click on "Menu" (in the top left corner of the page) then find "Keybindings"' and choose "None"...

Comment: The problem was indeed in keybinding. Solved when setting it to “None”